# Wifi seems network but stops at requesting Wifi address

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I just installed Lubuntu on my Packard Bell Easynote R3500. Network  by cable works like a charm but Wifi does not. Wifi sees the networks but when connecting to it it keeps hanging at
'Requesting a Wifi network Address for...'

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:40:d0:a2:d8:4e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.130  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::240:d0ff:fea2:d84e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10873803 (10.8 MB)  TX bytes:1349539 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:203532 (203.5 KB)  TX bytes:203532 (203.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:60:af:16:f5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:60ff:feaf:16f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21022 (21.0 KB)  TX bytes:43020 (43.0 KB)
```

Connecting to a wifi without a password also does not work.

Kind regards,
Paul

Comment: Have you added the WiFi through Network Connections?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across the same problem. Wired connection works great, wireless hangs at 'Requesting a Wifi network Address for...'

In my case, the problem was that I had the IPv4 set for manual (I need a static IP).  Not a problem via wired LAN, but would not connect that way via WiFi.  Changing IPv4 to Automatic (DHCP) got it to connect.  Then I added "additional static address" to get the IP I needed...  I don't know if this is the best solution, it does not seem very elegant, but it got the job done.